# Nativescript Android 8.0 READ_CALL_LOG Failed

Tags: nativescript, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

Using Nativescript 5.0.

Below piece of code works well in Android ver 6.0.1

But fails to get permission in Android 8.0

Permission seeking message box does not appear.

Difference observed in both phone's permission details is, in Android 8.0, additional permission is seen as "Dial through contacts" which can not be set manually.

```
Permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, "Needed for connectivity status").then(() => {
            console.log("refresh - Permission granted!");
            this.readCallLog();
            alert("in refresh Permission granted");
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log("Permission is not granted (sadface)");
            alert("in refresh Permission NOT granted");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

But to be precise nothing was changed in Android 8, but Android 9 introduced breaking changes to read call log permission which now requires phone state permission too to work.

Comment: Additionally I tried these too, but no luck.

[android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG,android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE]

Comment: Manoj, is there any document ready for Nativescript to access permission in Android 9?

Comment: You will have to refer the official Android docs for breaking changes with Android APIs. Nativescript would document only the framework related changes.

Answer (score 0):

While with earlier Android versions you could just request permission `READ_CALL_LOG` the newer Android versions are introducing some changes in how you could request the user call logs. The idea is to provide more information to the user explaining why you need these permissions.

An explanatory strings values should be provided in the Andorid resources

```
<string name="permgroupdesc_calllog">read and write phone call log</string>
<string name="permgrouprequest_calllog">Allow &lt;b>%1$s&lt;/b> to access your phone call logs?</string>
```

Also, you will need to ask for a number of permissions and not just `READ_CALL_LOG`:

```
CALL_LOG
READ_CALL_LOG
WRITE_CALL_LOG
ROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
```

Details on the above [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-p-read-call-log-phone-number/)